# Using selenium script to test URL but after browser opens, it does not point to the requested URL

Tags: python, django, selenium

I am following [this tutorial](https://www.obeythetestinggoat.com/book/pre-requisite-installations.html#_some_error_messages_youre_likely_to_see_when_you_inevitably_fail_to_activate_your_virtualenv) to learn more about Test-Driven Development with Django but have hit a snag.

In tutorial we are asked to use the following code which, when run, opens up my Firefox browser and dircts to the URL (http://localhost:8000).

```
from selenium import webdriver

browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get('http://localhost:8000')

assert 'Django' in browser.title
```

When run (using PyCharm), the browser opens with no issue but does not direct to the URL and the address bar remains blank. If I manually type in the URL it shows what should appear.

After some searching the only real results I found were that there were compatibility issues but after updating everything I am still encountering the error.

Does anyone have any suggestions as to resources to help solve the issue or maybe know a solution?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Is there a server at `localhost:8000`? What happens if you use something like `http://stackoverflow.com` instead?

Comment: @mblakesley I receive the same result. It opens up firefox with an orange address bar saying "search or enter address".

If I type localhost:8000 it comes up with the default Django page.

Comment: You're running PyCharm under a different environemnt?

Comment: @kerwei thank you for the comment. I just tried running it through terminal (Ubuntu) using my virtual environment and ended at the same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it usually happen because you have incompatible version between Firefox and geckodriver, update both software, for latest geckodriver you can get it [here](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases).

Comment: So I tried updating both software but now when I run it I get the error "Your Firefox profile cannot be loaded. It may be missing or inaccessible."

I created a new profile and still receive the same error.

Comment: there many possibilities but you can try to find the answer [here](https://www.google.com/search?q=your+firefox+profile+cannot+be+loaded+ubuntu+site:askubuntu.com)

Comment: I do not but I believe your solution is correct. I will be working on it again today. Thank you for your time.